# wait for a file to be created

Tags: file, vbscript

I have written a program in vbs and it should do the following. First of all it executes a program that I wrote in C++. At the end of that program a file is created. So I want my vbs script to wait until that program has finished and I tried to use this to wait for the file to be created.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
While (Not(fso.FileExists("D:\dev\FF\temp.asm")))
Wend
```

Once this has happened it should execute a following program.

Now I noticed that it is not really working so I am not sure if the loop was set up correctly.
Could anyone tell me how to wait for a file to be created correctly?

EDIT: Right now I am using this code:

```
folder="D:/dev/FF"
x=inputbox("name of your file (no extension)")

Set a = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Return = a.Run("frankifier2 "&folder&" "&x&".ff", 1, true)
```

And I am getting following error:

> Line: 5
>   Char: 1
>   Error: Unable to wait for process.
>   Code: 80020009
>   Source: WshShell.Run

Comment: Usually you get that error when there are leading spaces in the command line (`a.Run(" fra...`). Please double-check that the code you posted is the same one you're using. Also try echoing the command line before execution for debugging: `cmd = "frankifier2 " & folder & " " & x & ".ff" : WScript.Echo "_" & cmd & "_" : Return = a.Run(cmd, 1, True)`

Comment: My cmd command is used as expected and still it gives me the error.

Comment: Is `frankifier2` a batch file? or, is it some kind of 16bit application? Both options can generate problems.

Comment: Apparently it's *not* used as expected, otherwise we wouldn't be having this conversation. What does the output of `WScript.Echo "_" & cmd & "_"` look like? Can you run the command successfully in `CMD`?

Comment: I get _frankifier2 D:/dev/FF hello.ff_ as output. frankifier2 is a .exe created with C++. At the end of that .cpp file I have this code:
ofstream myfile ("temp.asm");  
   if (myfile.is_open()) {
    myfile << asmfile.str();
    myfile.close();
   }
   else cout << "Unable to open file";

The 2 specified parameters are only handled during program execution so that doesn't have to do anything with this because this error is displayed before the program is executed.

Comment: I don't see leading or trailing underscore in your output. Please follow the instructions you're given. Also, have you tried running the command in `CMD` (`a.Run("%COMSPEC% /c frankifier2 ...", 1, True)`)? Replace `/c` with `/k` to keep the `CMD` window open after execution.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Run method with the "wait on return" boolean set to true.  This has worked for me in the past.  Here's a link to MSDN about it:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: I got an error which said that it is unable to wait for the current process. I have this:
Set a = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Return = a.Run("frankifier2 "&folder&" "&x&".ff", 1, true)

Comment: Hmm, try the Exec method:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: @user2812868 Please update your question with the code you're currently using and the error (error number, message, line number) it raises.

Comment: Could be an issue with the quotes.  Please look at this Q&A: http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/problem-trying-run-program-script-waiting-result-help-105557692.html

Comment: Doing a quick search around the internet, one way to tell if a file is in use is by trying to open the file. You could possibly just try and do fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 8, False) on your file to see if you are able to open it. If you can't open it, you will know it is in use

Answer (score 1):

I shoud DRY this code up one day. It contains two almost identical functions.

```
runMyCppProgram filename  
If Not waitAbit(filename) Then Exit Sub 'or whatever else you wanna do here. The file is still not available after the timeout period.  
doSomethingElseOnFile filename  

Function waitAbit(filepath)  
    waitAbit = true  
    If Not waitTilExists (filepath, true) Then  
        MsgBox "Timeout. File not found: " & filepath, vbExclamation, "waitTilExists: error creating file"  
        waitAbit = false  
    End If  
    If Not waitTilUnlocked (filepath, true) Then  
        MsgBox "Timeout. File locked: " & filepath, vbExclamation, "waitTilUnlocked: error creating file"  
        waitAbit = false  
    End If  
End Function  

Function waitTilUnlocked (ByVal file, withRepeat)  
    ' dependency: the function fileIsLocked (file)  
    ' Sleeps until the file is unlocked  
    ' The polling interval will increase gradually, but never rises above MAX_WAITTIME  
    ' Times out after TIMEOUT msec. Will return false if caused by timeout.  
    Dim waittime, totalwaittime, rep, doAgain  
    Const INIT_WAITTIME = 20  
    Const MAX_WAITTIME = 1000  
    Const TIMEOUT = 5000  
    Const SLOPE = 1.1  
    file = replace (file, Chr(34), "") 'remove double quotes from the input  
    doAgain  = true  
    Do While doAgain  
        waittime = INIT_WAITTIME  
        totalwaittime = 0  
        Do While totalwaittime < TIMEOUT  
            waittime = Int (waittime * SLOPE)  
            If waittime>MAX_WAITTIME Then waittime=MAX_WAITTIME  
            totalwaittime = totalwaittime + waittime  
            WScript.sleep waittime  
            If Not fileIsLocked (file) Then  
                waitTilUnlocked = true  
                Exit Function  
            End If  
        Loop  
        If withRepeat Then  
            rep = MsgBox ("This file is locked:" & vbcr & file & vbcr & vbcr & "Keep trying?", vbRetryCancel+vbExclamation, "Locked file")  
            doAgain = (rep = vbRetry)  
        Else  
            doAgain = false  
        End If  
    Loop  

    waitTilUnlocked = false  
End Function  

Function fileIsLocked (file)  
    ' Returns true if the file is locked, and false if it is not.  
    ' If the files does not exist, false is returned  
    Dim ts  
    On Error Resume Next  
    If Not fso.fileExists (file) Then  
        fileIsLocked = False  
        Exit Function  
    End If  
    Set ts = fso.openTextFile (file, 8, False)  'ForAppending = 8  
     If Err.Number = 70 Then   'Permission denied  
         fileIsLocked = True  
     ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 then  
         WScript.Echo  "Unexpected Error #: " & Err.Number  
         fileIsLocked = False  
     Else  
         fileIsLocked = False  
     End If  
     Err.Clear  
    On Error GoTo 0  
End Function  

Function waitTilExists (ByVal file, withRepeat)  
    ' Sleeps until the file exists  
    ' The polling interval will increase gradually, but never rises above MAX_WAITTIME  
    ' Times out after TIMEOUT msec. Will return false if caused by timeout.  
    Dim waittime, totalwaittime, rep, doAgain  
    Const INIT_WAITTIME = 20  
    Const MAX_WAITTIME = 1000  
    Const TIMEOUT = 5000  
    Const SLOPE = 1.1  
    file = replace (file, Chr(34), "") 'remove double quotes from the input  
    doAgain  = true  
    Do While doAgain  
        waittime = INIT_WAITTIME  
        totalwaittime = 0  
        Do While totalwaittime < TIMEOUT  
            waittime = Int (waittime * SLOPE)  
            If waittime>MAX_WAITTIME Then waittime=MAX_WAITTIME  
            totalwaittime = totalwaittime + waittime  
            WScript.sleep waittime  
            If fso.fileExists (file) Then  
                waitTilExists = true  
                Exit Function  
            End If  
        Loop  
        If withRepeat Then  
            rep = MsgBox ("This file does not exist:" & vbcr & file & vbcr & vbcr & "Keep trying?", vbRetryCancel+vbExclamation, "File not found")  
            doAgain = (rep = vbRetry)  
        Else  
            doAgain = false  
        End If  
    Loop  

    waitTilExists = false  
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but your code should work as well.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
While Not fso.FileExists("D:\dev\FF\temp.asm")
  Wscript.echo "File Not Found"
Wend
```

Comment: as the file may well *exist* before the external program has finished writing to it, the strategy won't work reliably.